# Internal Server error during file uploading in laravel5.3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3, server-error

I am trying to upload a file in laravel.But every time i hit the submit button it gives me the internal server error in the console. I have checked the rote with a get request to check if the controller function is working properly and it works fine. Can any say what is the problem? 
here is my code samples

> route code

```
Route::post('/storefile','PublicationController@storeFile');
```

> controller

```
public function storeFile(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){
            echo "got";
        }
        else echo "not ajax";
    }
```

> view

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('stylesheet')
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap-tagging.css" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection
@section('content')
    <div class="validation-system">
        <div class="validation-form">
            <form id="test-form" action="/storepublication" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                {!! csrf_field() !!}           
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group1">
                    <label class="control-label">Upload Paper</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="paper">
                </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 form-group1">
                    <input type="submit"  id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#test-form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var file_data = $('#paper').prop('files')[0];
                var form_data = new FormData();
                form_data.append('file', file_data);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/storefile",
                    type: "post",
                    data: form_data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (res) {
                        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
                    }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this

```
var file_data = $('#paper').prop('files')[0];
```

by this

```
var file_data = $('#paper').files[0];
```

Comment: No that doesn't help

Comment: Did you check with `if($request->file('file'))` in your controller instead `if($request->ajax())`

Comment: yes did it just now. No change. Just found that on server-side I'm having token mismatch exception. I have tried this too  data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", "paper":form_data} but yet the mismatch exception is there

Comment: Add `form_data.append('_token', $("input[name='_token']").val());`