# How to send files in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two scripts

first in Vue component:

```
var data = {
    cover: myResult[0], // first file
    file: myResult[1], // second file
    title: self.title, // first string
    desc: self.desc // second string
};
self.$http.post('tracks.post', data)
    .then(res =>{
         console.log(data); // 1*
         console.log(res); //  2*
})
```

And php script on server:

```
dd(file_get_contents('php://input')); // 3*
dd($_FILES); // 4*
```

dd() - just a function to see what in parametr

1* - all is good, all strings and file exists:

```
Object {cover: File, file: File, title: "ada", desc: "asdasd"}
```

2* - not all is good (explanation next)
3* - there shows only strings, but files are disappeared:

```
string(52) "{"cover":{},"file":{},"title":"ada","desc":"asdasd"}"↵
```

4* - in $_FILES also not exists files:

```
array(0) {↵}↵
```

So, How I should to send files in vuejs?

Comment: I sent file from vuejs to laravel , hope it works in core php also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579070/internal-server-error-during-file-uploading-in-laravel5-3/42579340

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to send files in VueJS. What I do know is that I ran into a similar issue with angularjs a year ago. My solution was to use javascript FormObject() for sending data to the server instead of just using Object(). I also had to write a custom directive which looked like this

```
<input data-file id="id_image" name="image" ng-model="museumMap" type="file">

myApp.directive('file', function() {
    return {
        require:"ngModel",
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, el, attrs, ngModel){
            el.bind('change', function(event){
                var files = event.target.files;
                var file = files[0];

                ngModel.$setViewValue(file);
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I know this doesnt directly answer your question, but hopefully it gives you a starting point. Id try using FormObject() first.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of tests, I founded right way to post files with strings:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('token', self.$auth.getToken());
data.append('file', file);
data.append('cover', cover);
data.append('title', self.title);
data.append('desc', self.desc);
```

And then just send the data as usuall. Hope it helps someone in future.